# How to make table cells of different types using React-Tables library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have this project where each cell must have a different type: Some of them are inputs, some of them are dropdowns, and on some of them I have to implement a modal hen I click the cell.

I am using react tables and I can't find a way to render different type of cells in the same table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap for table. it is very easy to use to get responsive table.

Comment: I am trying to use more functions available with react-tables library, such as Filtering, sorting, pagination. That's why I'm trying to stick with this